# Mixing keyword and default arguments in python 3.5.1

Tags: python, keyword, default-value

I'm a newbie and taking an online python class through an online workbook. I can't seem to figure out how to get the output to display like the example shown:

Problem instructions:
Write a function number_of_pennies() that returns the total number of pennies given a number of dollars and (optionally) a number of pennies. Ex: 5 dollars and 6 pennies returns 506.

Here is what I have:

```
def number_of_pennies(dollars = (),pennies=())

    return number_of_pennies
print(number_of_pennies(5, 6)) # Should print 506
print(number_of_pennies(4))    # Should print 400
```

Thanks to your help I just changed it to this:

```
def number_of_pennies(dollars = 0,pennies=0):
    number_of_pennies= (dollars * 100) + pennies
    return number_of_pennies
print(number_of_pennies(5, 6)) # Should print 506
print(number_of_pennies(4))    # Should print 400
```

Comment: multiply dollars by 100, and add pennies to it - that would be the first step. .Rest would be edge case handling.. Why dont you try that first, and edit the question if you still find yourself stuck.

Comment: Why are you using empty `tuple`s (parenthesis) as your defaults for dollars and pennies? If someone didn't pass in a dollar or penny amount, would it be more reasonable to use `dollars=0, pennies=0` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Default arguments are used when the caller doesn't supply a value. So, what should be the default? In your case, if the user doesn't supply dollars, zero dollars seems like a reasonable choice. Same with pennies. Since `number_of_pennies(4)` should be `400` you know that they want dollars to be the first parameter. The remainder is just the math.

`number_of_pennies` is just the name of the function which would be an odd thing to return. In fact, when you try it you get something like `<function number_of_pennies at 0x7ff4e962d488>` which means that the function returned its own function object. Instead return the data you calculate... that's much more useful!

```
>>> def number_of_pennies(dollars=0, pennies=0):
...     return dollars * 100 + pennies
... 
>>> print(number_of_pennies(5,6))
506
>>> print(number_of_pennies(4))
400
```

Comment: Thanks so much folks! I followed your suggestions and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```py
def number_of_pennies(dollars = 0, pennies = 0):
    return dollars * 100 + pennies

print(number_of_pennies(int(input()), int(input()))) # Both dollars and pennies
print(number_of_pennies(int(input())))               # Dollars only
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you explain with a few words what your code does?

Answer (score 0):

```
def number_of_pennies(n,x=0):
    return n*100+x
```

Answer (score -1):

I did the same workbork. This is what I came up with:

```
def number_of_pennies(dollars=0, pennies=0):
    dollars = dollars * 100
    pennies = pennies
    total = dollars + pennies
    return total

print(number_of_pennies(int(input()), int(input()))) # Both dollars and pennies
print(number_of_pennies(int(input())))               # Dollars only
```